# Ошибка InflateException при запуске приложения

Tags: android, imageview

При запуске приложения на эмуляторе все работает хорошо, но при запуске приложения на реальном устройстве появляется ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.proj/com.company.proj.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
```

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.company.proj.HomeActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_enter_sn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:text="@string/enter_sn"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_enter_sn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_enter_sn"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_vk">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/vkontakte"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_facebook">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_or_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_enter_sn"
        android:text="@string/or_email"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_or_mail"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/dark_blue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        android:text="@string/log_in"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/sign_up" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeActivity.class:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: нужен код самой Activity, метод onCreate()

Comment: похоже проблема в форматах файлов, которые у вас в ресурсах. Закиньте туда какой либо проверенный (который точно отображается) файл-картинку и попробуйте запустить снова, отпишите результат..

Comment: ZigZag, с любой картинкой вылезает ошибка

Comment: в какой папке лежат drawable ресурсы?

Comment: Какое разрешение у используемых изображений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в image векторное изображение? Возможно, проблема в этом.

Попробуйте прописать в onCreate (перед setContentView)

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

В build.gradle (*app*)

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

также

замените

```
android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

на

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
```

Comment: TimurVI, не помогло

Comment: @Anna13: обновил немного ответ